# Angular Bind Context Between

Tags: angular

Hí,

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hzk6hp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponent%2Fsubform%2Fsubform.component.ts)

I have a component called **SubFormComponent** inside it I have another one called **ItemComponent**. I'm going through a property binding function inside the **SubFormComponent** and executing it inside the **ItemComponent**.
The problem is that I want that, when this function is executed in the **ItemComponent**, it has the *CONTEXT* from which it was created (**SubFormComponent**).

I tried to use bind, call and apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go is to use a closure, so your function definition would be:

```
anyFunction(ctx) {
  return (callback = null) => {
    if ( callback ) callback(ctx);
  }
}
```

and you would pass it as binding by calling it with a context

```
[func]='anyFunction(this)'
```

Although this should work, I would bet there are better ways to do what you want, without passing component instances around like this via function params.